# How can I update a value inside onMount() in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Im trying to change the value of one variable inside onMount, but i cant, this is my attempt, how can I achieve to print, for example this... [Here the REPL in svelte.dev](https://svelte.dev/repl/105c7b3ca7f043a5bb345d40231e9676?version=3.41.0)

```
<script>


    import { onMount } from "svelte"
    
    let qrActive = false
    console.log(qrActive)

    const handleQr = () => {
        qrActive = !qrActive
    }

    const qr = (qrActive) => {
        if (qrActive) {
            console.log("working");
        } else {
            console.log("Nothing :v")  
        }
    }

    $: onMount( () => qr(qrActive))

</script>


<button on:click={handleQr}>
  Change!
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`onMount` only runs once, it cannot be run again.
you might be able to use `beforeUpdate` or `afterUpdate` or just reactivity

```js
$: qr(qrActive)
```

The above code will execute *qr* everytime *qrActive* changes